# how to solve the frame ID setting warning?

Tags: slam, navigation, joint-trajectory-controller, hector, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have any idea ** to correct the following warning setting?

```
[WARN] [1340092854.777455509]: Message from [/hokuyo] has a non-fully-qualified
```

frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[WARN] [1340092854.968655384]: Message from [/hector_mapping] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ERROR][1340123076.274228430]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]
[ERROR] [1340123076.523439543]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36857/how-to-solve-the-frame-id-setting-warning?/) by [jas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2638/jas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set the frame_id to /laser and the warnings will go away.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kedarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5211/kedarm/) on 2013-10-03**:
Although I agree that this solution will work for single robot settings, I think a better and more robust solution is given here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5511

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Frames gets defined in a hierarchy like parent_frame/child_frame. If a frame do not have any parent, it is defined as /frame. First warning is :

```
 Message from [/hokuyo] has a non-fully-qualified  frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser].
```

It is advisable to fully specify the hierarchy when using frames as using just name could lead to ambiguity in choosing the correct frame. This will definitely cause problem in multi-robot scenario. About following errors:

```
[ERROR][1340123076.274228430]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map] [ERROR] [1340123076.523439543]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]
```

You are not publishing tf for:   map --> base_link

Point no. 17 at link http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/FAQ will be helpful

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1